# Rspec test call method send reconfirmation instruction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking, rspec-rails

I’m using Rspec to test the case when user change password, mail will be sent. And I want to check that only 1 mail is sent. I don't want use `Action::Mailer.deliveries` to check, instead I want to check that whether method is called and how much.

On searching I found `Test Spy` from rspec mock:
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#test-spies

```rb
describe 'PUT /email' do
  include_context 'a user has signed in', { email: 'old-email@example.com', password: 'correct_password' }

  context  'correct new email, correct password' do
    before do
      allow(user).to receive(:send_reconfirmation_instructions)
    end

    it do
      should == 302
      expect(user.reload.unconfirmed_email).to eq 'new-email@example.com'
      expect(user).to receive(:send_reconfirmation_instructions).once
    end
  end
end
```

But I got error:

```
  Failure/Error: expect(user).to receive(:send_reconfirmation_instructions)

   (#<User id: 1269, email: “old-email@example.com”, created_at: “2019-08-27 03:54:33", updated_at: “2019-08-27 03:54:33”...“>).send_reconfirmation_instructions(*(any args))
       expected: 1 time with any arguments
       received: 0 times with any arguments
```

`send_reconfirmation_instructions` this function is from devise: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L124-L130

I did `binding.pry` and I’m sure that the test jump inside this function but rspec still failed.

Edit:
I could make it kind of work by writing like this:

```rb
describe 'PUT /email' do
  include_context 'a user has signed in', { email: 'old-email@example.com', password: 'correct_password' }

  context  'correct new email, correct password' do
    before do
      expect_any_instance_of(User).to receive(:send_reconfirmation_instructions).once
    end

    it do
      should == 302
      expect(user.reload.unconfirmed_email).to eq 'new-email@example.com'
      # expect(user).to receive(:send_reconfirmation_instructions).once
    end
  end
end
```

However I got another error:

```
Failure/Error: 
(#<User user_id: 1418, email: “old-email@example.com”...“>).send_reconfirmation_instructions(#<User user_id: 1418, email: “old-email@example.com” ...“>)
                expected: 1 time with any arguments
                received: 2 times with arguments: (#<User user_id: 1418, email: “old-email@example.com”, id: 1323...“>)
```

Comment: It is unclear from your question where `user` was defined. But I guess `user` is the instance of the user that was created in the database before the test starts. Whereas the code later loads another instance (of the same user) from the database. That means the method in question is indeed not called on that `user` instance but on another instance of the same record that was loaded in your controller. I guess that method is calling a mailer, why don't you mock the mailer?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes you're right, instance from rspec and instance from controller are different. I could make it work by using `expect_any_instance_of(User)`

Answer (score 1):

The line where you're checking that the user has received the message should read:

```rb
expect(user).to have_received(:send_reconfirmation_instructions).once
```

instead of:

```rb
expect(user).to receive(:send_reconfirmation_instructions).once
```

The former where you say `expect(obj).to have_received(:msg)` requires you to assert that the message was called, as you intended to do.

The latter, on the other hand, where you say `expect(obj).to receive(:msg)` is a way to set up the expectation before the action, i.e. in lieu of the `allow(obj).to receive(:msg)` without requiring to assert that it was called after the action. After the spec ran, it will automatically assert whether it was called.

This explains the error you're getting when specifying

```rb
expect(user).to receive(:send_reconfirmation_instructions).once
```

as no code after that line sends that message to `user`, which gets verified after the spec.

Comment: Wow thanks so much for point out the different between these two. I thought they are the same @@